# how to make listview like android market . i.e divided into two columns

Tags: android, android-listview

I was wondering how to implement the `listview` like the android market.

[image]

in the right hand panel a `listview` is divided into the two rows. This is very useful because it saves lot of space and user can look at almost double items in the `listview` at a time. how can I implement this ? any suggestions?

Comment: The first is customview. The second image is `GridView`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use GridView instead of ListView of two columns..

[1. GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

[2. GridViewExample](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)

Sample design : [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Silent Killer . This might be the solution to my problem! I'll try it .

Answer (score 2):

The Android Market also uses the [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) to scroll between the pages. [Here](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/) is an example on how you could implement it.

Answer (score 1):

There is another question that is related to this one.Check the folling link, it might help you:

[How to display a two column ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432951/how-to-display-a-two-column-listview-in-android)

Modify you *.xml file to get what you want.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to do this using listView, then each item (row) in the list view should consist of two views. You can do this using a relative layout (or linear layout) with two items side by side.
2. You can also implement this using a gridview having two columns.

Comment: I'll have a look at gridview . But I'll like to know more on how to add two views into the listview.

Comment: Take a look at the following tutorial. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ Take a note of how the list_row.xml is laid out.

Comment: @rahul I don't think that the example that you mentioned is an appropriate example for two-column listview. It implements a custom layout for a listview. And my question is if you implement a two-column listview row than how can you handle the OnItemClick method when the two items are represented as a whole single item.