# Two listview in different columns in android

Tags: android, listview

How we can  place a two listview in different column.when one list(list with arrow image) is clicked,next list is coming on the right side(not on below)?

Comment: use fragments each one with listviews one for each fragment

Comment: thank you for valuable reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an idea by following these:

- [How to display a two column ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432951/how-to-display-a-two-column-listview-in-android)
- [Android-multi-column-listview](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/)
- [Multicolumn-listview-in-android/](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)

Comment: But i am having 2 different listviews.your post is on one listview.I found a solution.one with fragments.another with different layouts.ie,by creating 2 layouts vertically and placing the lists on each layout

Comment: then i should recommend you for fragments as it is more powerful and reliable than others.