# Listview repeating information

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to do a listview with 2 database collumn. I succeded but my problem is that only the first information of the database appears in the listview. If i have x data in the database it will show the x rows in the listview with only the first entry.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
data = new ArrayList();
    Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM projeto", null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Caminhos:", 3000).show();
        data.clear();
        do {
            data.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_proj")));
            data.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
            map.put("id", data.get(0).toString());
            map.put("nome", data.get(1).toString());
            map.put("hora", "17:00");
            mylist.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());


        SimpleAdapter resul = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mylist,R.layout.list_item,new String[] {"id", "nome", "hora"}, new int[] {R.id.i, R.id.n, R.id.h});
        lista.setAdapter(resul);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a two column ListView in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432951/how-to-display-a-two-column-listview-in-android)

Comment: i saw that post, it didnt help me :(

Comment: Why are you not using a `CursorAdapter`? Skip the step of transferring all that data to Maps and Lists and stuff, just use the Cursor directly. In fact, the ArrayList called `data` is useless here -- you add to it and then read from it when putting values into the map, when you could just add directly to the map in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

- You don't clear data (Like said in a previous answer) so you always get the first two values
- You always use the same map. Since map is an object you will always modify the same and your list will be fill will one map.

To fix this two points try this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
data = new ArrayList();
Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM projeto", null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Caminhos:", 3000).show();
    do {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data.clear();
        data.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_proj")));
        data.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
        map.put("id", data.get(0).toString());
        map.put("nome", data.get(1).toString());
        map.put("hora", "17:00");
        mylist.add(map);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());


    SimpleAdapter resul = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mylist,R.layout.list_item,new String[] {"id", "nome", "hora"}, new int[] {R.id.i, R.id.n, R.id.h});
    lista.setAdapter(resul);
```

Comment: It's working but now the problem is that i have 2 entries in the BD and it is showing in the listview 4, it's repeating two times. I think it's because the map.put() its inside the loop but if i take out it only saves the last entry.

Comment: Forget it, i was using the same DB. It's working fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

look at this,

```
map.put("id", data.get(0).toString());
map.put("nome", data.get(1).toString());
map.put("hora", "17:00");
```

You always put the same key in the map, always "id, nome and hora" you need put diferent key.

ps: Why you create a List of Map? You don't need to this.

Comment: so what do you think i should do?? i just want to show the id and the name of the person, the third field ("hora") is an extra.

Comment: Look here, http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear `data` each time through the loop.  You need to move your call to `data.clear()` to just after the `do {` loop begins.  What you're doing at the moment will mean that after the first item is retrieved from the cursor, data will contain 2 items. After the second time it will contain 4, then 6, etc. You then always read the same two items. If you clear `data` it should fix your problem.

Comment: it didn't fix the problem

Comment: You also need to add a new map each time through the loop rather than reusing the same one.